# How do I find the actual weather data that is pulled with Beautiful Soup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to code a weather notification app in Python and I am having trouble finding the actual weather data so I can pull my variables later in the code. This is my first actual program so any help would be appreciated!

```
import bs4, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
n = ToastNotifier()
def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
htmldata = getdata("https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/cbaac1d32c1c53fb17b70538d11fb0f7a9b126f58b9515261d847f28c846d32c")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
current_temp = soup.find_all("span", class_= "_-_-components-src-organism-CurrentConditions-CurrentConditions--tempValue--MHmYY")
chances_rain = soup.find_all("div", class_= "_-_-components-src-organism-CurrentConditions-CurrentConditions--precipValue--2aJSf")
temp = (str(current_temp))
temp_rain = str(chances_rain)
result = "The current temp is " + temp[128:-9] + "in some City" + "\n" + temp_rain[131:-14]
n.show_toast("Live Weather Update", result, duration = 15)
input()
```

Comment: If you just want to build a weather app, I recommend using a [dedicated weather API](https://openweathermap.org/api) rather than web scraping.

Comment: For an actual app, I would probably go that route, right now I'm just learning python so I'm trying to see what everything does. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code how to scrape location, weather,as of time, info ...

Instead of print in each function you can add addtional code you need or adjust my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_content = requests.get("https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/cbaac1d32c1c53fb17b70538d11fb0f7a9b126f58b9515261d847f28c846d32c").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')


def find_location():
    locator = 'div.CurrentConditions--header--27uOE h1.CurrentConditions--location--kyTeL'  # CSS locator
    item = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(item)


def find_weather():
    locator = 'div.CurrentConditions--primary--2SVPh span.CurrentConditions--tempValue--3a50n'
    weather = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(weather)


def find_weather_type():
    locator = 'div.CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W'
    type_of = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(type_of)


def info():
    locator = "div.CurrentConditions--precipValue--3nxCj span"
    info_text = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(info_text)

def as_of_time():
    locator = "div.CurrentConditions--timestamp--23dfw"
    as_of = soup.select_one(locator).string
    print(as_of)

find_location()
find_weather()
find_weather_type()
info()
as_of_time()
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help!